# Compile on heroku node ts- jest types- cannot find type definition

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku, jestjs

I'm getting following error while deploying on heroku, and I'm unable to fix it. 
Build on local works fine.

> error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '@types/jest'. The
> file is in the program because: Entry point of type library
> '@types/jest' specified in compilerOptions

My tsconfig file:

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["jest", "node"],
    "typeRoots": ["./ts-declarations", "node_modules/@types", "./src/types/global"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Package.json

```
  "name": "tasker-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --detectOpenHandles --watchAll  --verbose",
    "start": "nodemon -e ts,js --exec ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register --files ./app.ts",
    "start:prod": "node dist/app",
    "build": "tsc --project tsconfig.build.json && tsc-alias"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/sequelize": "^4.28.14",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-session": "^1.0.2",
    "sequelize": "^6.21.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.6",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.8",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/passport": "^1.0.9",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "babel-preset-typescript": "^7.0.0-alpha.19",
    "jest": "^28.1.1",
    "node-mocks-http": "^1.11.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "supertest": "^6.2.3",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.1",
    "tsc-alias": "^1.7.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.build only adds exclude for test files

heroku post build script
`"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false cd client && yarn install && yarn build && cd .. && cd backend && yarn install && yarn build"`

Comment: Please show your `package.json`.

Comment: @Chris post edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your `@types` are `devDependencies`, as they should be. That means that, by default, [they are not available at runtime](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#package-installation).

The problem is that your `start` script is running a *development* command, including `nodemon` instead of `node`, and running the uncompiled TypeScript instead of the built JavaScript.

It looks like you already have a production script called `start:prod`, but that's not a standard script so Heroku has no idea what it is. I suggest you simply rename that script to `start` and rename your existing development script to `start:dev`:

```json
"start:dev": "nodemon -e ts,js --exec ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register --files ./app.ts",
"start": "node dist/app",
```

Then commit and redeploy.

Comment: Thanks for help @Chris , thats help a little cause I messed app with script names.
But I finally compiled correctly when I moved ts ts-alias and types from devDependencies to dependecies like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68975342/heroku-build-cant-find-types-in-package-json-file

Comment: @SmgTR, that is not the correct solution. You shouldn't be running `nodemon` or TypeScript in production. Use your production build in production, not your development files.